# Mounting an existing partition of an unmounted disk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, diskmanagement, partition

I ran the `fdisk -l` command to show me all the disks and partitions. Here's the output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0003c54f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          32      248832   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              32      121602   976510977    5  Extended
/dev/sda5              32      121602   976510976   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e92b3

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1      119513   959986688   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2          119514      121602    16773121    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5          119514      121602    16773120   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00089d08

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1          32      248832   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdc2              32      121602   976510977    5  Extended
/dev/sdc5              32      121602   976510976   8e  Linux LVM
```

Currently my mounted partitions are `/dev/sdb1` and  `/dev/sdb2`. I have some data on the partition `/dev/sda2` that I'd like to access. How can i mount this temporarily so that I can access it? Running `mount /dev/sda2` gives me an error saying `mount: can't find /dev/sda2 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab`.

Comment: It's unlikely that that description is true.  `/dev/sdb2` is a container partition, which is unlikely to be mounted.  `/dev/sda2` is a container partition too, and will not have "data that I'd like to access", that being the province of one of the contained partitions.

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/sda2` is the "[Extended](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Extended_partition)" partition containing `/dev/sda5`.  There is no data there (other than the contents of `/dev/sda5`).

In the general case, though, if you don't have an entry in `/etc/fstab` with the mounting options, you'll need to provide all of the options to mount:

```
mount /dev/something /some/directory/to/mount/to
```

Possibly with `-t filesystemtype` if mount is unable to autodetect it.